# How to make the list of results from a search-bar navigatable via up/down arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I am trying to implement a search-bar that displays results from our database. I already have the results displaying, but I need to make it such that I can navigate the results using the up/down arrows.

Given below is the HTML structure of the searchbar: an input segment, and a div with the 'list of results'. Inside the list of results, for each result is a div that includes the result's properties.

I am working with Ember.js.

```
{{!-- Contains the whole Searchbar.  --}}
<div class="searchbarContainer" tabindex="-1" bubbles=false>
    {{input type="search" name="searchFor" class="searchTextField" placeholder="Search..." value=searchKey}}
    <div class="searchResultsContainer box-shadow" {{bind-attr id="searchBarID"}}>
        {{#if searchKeyNotNull}}
                {{!-- For each Row, include visual elements. --}} 
                {{#each toSearch }}
                    <div class="resultRow" tabindex="-1"{{action 'didClickResultDefault' this}}>
                        <img {{bind-attr src="resultIcon" class=":resultIcon isRound:roundIcon"}}>

                        <div class="inline-block">
                            <div class="resultName">
                                {{unbound this.resultText}} 
                            </div><br>
                            <div class="resultTitle">
                                {{unbound this.secondaryText}} 
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

To clarify a few things: the way this works now is that searchKeyNotNull is a property on the controller to check if the input entered is not empty (to avoid unnecessary database call). toSearch is an array that is populated when results are fetched; on each character entry into the input portion, a query is made and toSearch is repopulated.

I should also point out that if the input box loses focus, the searchResultsContainer is immediately hidden. And the search-bar itself is an Ember Component, if that makes a difference at all.

The point is, at this stage, I have an array of results that I am displaying to the page. Each result is displayed in a div 'resultRow'; all 'resultRow's are in a parent div 'searchResultsContainer'. The goal is to be able to navigate through these resultRows using the up and down arrows; hitting enter should be akin to clicking the resultRow.

It seems that pretty much every searchbar in the world can be navigated using the keyboard but I have disheartingly failed to understand how such a feature is implemented - or even approached.

How is such a useful feature implemented?

Comment: did that answer your question or did you find another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341608/1146562

> Create a server-side script (PHP, Rails, ASP.net, etc) to generate your search results. The script can fetch data from wherever you like, for example a database or a hardcoded list. Your script must accept a GET parameter named q which will contain the term to search for. E.g. http://www.example.com/myscript?q=query

Link to plugin and documentation http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

*****************UPDATE********************

here is another answer that might point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810896/1146562

```
$("ul").keydown(function (e) {
    var searchbox = $(this);
    switch (e.which) {
        case 40:
            $('li:not(:last-child).selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
            break;
        case 38:
            $('li:not(:first-child).selected').removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected');
            break;
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much! i did end up using the plugin, although I had to tweak my structure quite a bit.